# Jersey: Returning a List<Map<String,Object>>> as XML

Tags: java, xml, rest, jaxb, jersey

I have a REST service that returns a `List<Map<String,Object>>` when a GET is performed on a particular resource. 
However it tries to return this list as `application/xml` and fails with the following exception:

> javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException:
>   com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java
>   class java.util.ArrayList, and Java type class java.util.ArrayList,
>   and MIME media type application/xml was not found

The stack trace also gives me the following information:

> The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media
>   type are: application/xml ->
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$App
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$App
>   com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$App
>   */* ->

It seems I am missing a message body writer. Given that I am not sending any custom classes in the response I assume a message body writer class must already be out there.
Is there a mising jar or config option I need to set to allow Jersey to return a List as xml?

Comment: I ended up implementing a javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter<List<Map<String, Object>>> to do this for me. I was expecting this to be something the framework provides out of the box.